# Cannot connect to socketio server from client in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
const { io } = require("socket.io-client");
const botSocket = io("http://localhost:1025");
botSocket.connect();

botSocket.on("connect_failed", function () {
  console.log("Sorry, there seems to be an issue with the connection!");
});

botSocket.onAny((data) => {
  console.log(data, "bot connect");
});

botSocket.on("connection", (data) => {
  console.log(data, "bot conenct");
});
```

Here is my code, but when I run it, nothing is logged ever, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Somewhere in the code, you should be calling `connect`?

Comment: It autoconnects but anyways, i have tried it still nothing [ updated code]

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: yes :D, take a look at updated code in question, i am calling botSocket.connect();

is it the right way?
thanks

Comment: Sorry my bad, my knowledge about the io API is outdated. But there is an event for connection errors : `connect_error` subscribe to that check if there is an error. [link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#event-connect_error)

Comment: Oh yea, i can see the errors, thanks! some xhr poll error